# How to Get counts from Cookies that a user Visits to site

Tags: cookies

I have a website like http://www.mydomain.com/Home.I am accessing many times this website from my system. Now I want to check using cookies that how many times I have Visited this website from my system.
Have I need to create cookies manualy or I have use browser cookies..
Plz let me know that how I can get this done.

Answer (score 0):

In your server side code, be it PHP or Asp, you can set cookies and send them back to the browser.

If you want to find how many times a website is visited by your browser, you should set and update the cookie in your server side code for every request.